# Combinatorics - Arranging boys/girls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Six girls are to enter a dance with 10 boys to form a ring so that every girl is between two boys: (a) What is the probability that some specified boy remains between 2 boys? (b)what is a the probability that mary, one of the girls, will stand next to harry, on of the boys?

My way of work:

part (a) - all boys stand in a line and used as partitions. so 10! for the boys. then, the first girl has 10 spots to choose, the next one ,9 and then 8 and 7.

so the total number of permitted settings is 10!1098765. 6 bouts stand next to a girl. at least on more boy can stand next to a girl, so 3 boys left so stand next only to boys. so the probability of a specific boy to stand next to 2 boys is: 3/10. is this correct?

part (b) - the chances of a girls stand next to a boy is 1. the chances of a boy to stand next to a girl is 1 minus the chance not to stand next to a girl .the answer is 1 - (answer from part 1) : 1 - 3/10 = 7/10.

not sure this is the correct answer.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: (b) is too vague to be answerable: what do the terms "certain" mean here and what would "random" even mean in this context?

Comment: @whuber you right, this question was posted by someone else and closed, so I reposted it. I edited part b, to as I understand it.

Comment: Attack (b) this way: count the number of possible positions Mary could select and count how many of them place her next to Harry.